# Javascript - Regex expression to split strings on semicolon, except when it is used inside single or double quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently using the following regex, but it fails when i have unclosed quotes.

```
const expression = /([^;"']+(("((\\")|[^"])*")|('((\\')|[^'])*')|[^;'"]*)*);?/gm;
const matchedArray = str.match(expression);
```

So this works fine: `str;that;works;`

And this as well: `str;that'works;';fine"always";`

But this fails: `str'doesn't work';` because it removes the last single quote

This also fails: `str'doesn\''t work';` because it removes the last single quote

So I need a regex that supports my existing strings and also the ones that break.
Thank you!

Comment: Write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to hide quoted strings before splitting and restore them afterwards. An escapen quote is no quote; nor an escaped semicolon, a semicolon. Unclosed quote lasts till the end of the string.

```js
let hidden = [];
   
const split = str => str
    .replace (/(?<!\\)'([^']|\\')*((?<!\\)'|$)|(?<!\\)"([^"]|\\")*((?<!\\)"|$)/g, s => '\x01' + hidden.push (s) + '\x02')
    .split (/(?<!\\);/)
    .map (s => {
      for (let i = 0; i < hidden.length; i++) {
        s = s.replace ('\x01' + (i + 1) + '\x02', hidden [i]);
      }
      return s;
    });
    
const tests = [
  `str;that'works;';fine"always";`,
  `str'doesn't work';`,
  `str'doesn\'t work';`,
  `str'doesn\\'t work';`,  
  `str'doesn\''t work';or does it?`,
  `str'doesn\\''t work';or does it?`  
];

for (let test of tests) {
  console.log (test + ' => ' + split (test));
}
```

Comment: This works great in chrome. But it crashes in firefox and safari. SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

Comment: @augustinilea, strange: I have run it in Firefox.

Comment: it seems that look behinds are supported from firefox v78, but in safari there is still no support.
https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind